# Inserting array of object into another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge two objects into one, but i need to makes sure that the first array of objects values and key become key values of another array of objects hopefully this makes sense:

So i have a dataConstant with some info like this:

```
export const tileData = [
    {
        title: 'JS CONS',
        skill: 40,
        visitTitle: 'Visit JS',
        visitUrl: 'https://www.google.co.uk'
    },
    {
        title: 'JS CONS',
        skill: 50,
        visitTitle: 'Visit JS',
        visitUrl: 'https://www.google.co.uk'
    }
]
```

I import this const into my React component. Inside the same I am importing multiple images and put them into array of objects like so:

```
//the values of the objects keys are imported logos
getLogos(tileData) {
    const logo = [{logo: js}, {logo: react}];
    var combi = [...logo, ...i];
    console.log(combi);
    return combi;
}
```

the result of this is:

```
0: {logo: "/static/media/js.a672e76f.png"}
1: {logo: "/static/media/react.5513eea1.png"}
2: {title: "JS CONS", skill: 40, visitTitle: "Visit JS", visitUrl: "https://www.google.co.uk"}
3: {title: "JS CONS", skill: 50, visitTitle: "Visit JS", visitUrl: "https://www.google.co.uk"}
```

But I would like the first two element `0` and `1` to be inside of the `3` and `4`

Comment: Did you mean `var combi = [...logo, ...tileData];`?

Comment: Hi John, just wrote you a solution, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let logos = [{logo: "/static/media/js.a672e76f.png"},{logo: "/static/media/react.5513eea1.png"}]

let tileData = [{title: "JS CONS", skill: 40, visitTitle: "Visit JS", visitUrl: "https://www.google.co.uk"},{title: "JS CONS", skill: 50, visitTitle: "Visit JS", visitUrl: "https://www.google.co.uk"}]
```

You can use `.map()` to combine the two arrays like so:

```
let combinedArr = logos.map((item, index) => {
    return {
    ...item,
    ...tileData[index]
    }
})
```

Results in:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
logo: "/static/media/js.a672e76f.png"
skill: 40
title: "JS CONS"
visitTitle: "Visit JS"
visitUrl: "https://www.google.co.uk"
__proto__: Object
1:
logo: "/static/media/react.5513eea1.png"
skill: 50
title: "JS CONS"
visitTitle: "Visit JS"
visitUrl: "https://www.google.co.uk"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Awesome @John! Please consider marking this as the answer :)